# how to cover more than 75% in test class for trigger?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I am stuck in test class, please help me.

This is my trigger:

```
trigger Rfleet_populateorderfromAccount on Order (before insert,before update) {
    Set<ID> orderids = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> AccDocid = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> accids = new Set<ID>();
    list<Order> updatebillingaddress=new list<Order>();

    for(Order Od : trigger.new){
        if(od.Rfleet_Vehicle_Billed_Customer__C != null  ){
            orderids.add(od.Rfleet_Vehicle_Billed_Customer__C);
        }else{
            system.debug('else---->');
            Od.BillingStreet = '';
            Od.BillingCity='';
            Od.BillingState = '';
            Od.BillingCountry= '';
            Od.BillingPostalCode ='';
        }
        if(od.Rfleet_Account_for_Document__c!=null) {  
            AccDocid.add(od.Rfleet_Account_for_Document__c);
        }else {
            od.ShippingStreet ='';
            od.ShippingCity= '';
            od.ShippingState = '';
            od.ShippingCountry= '';
            od.ShippingPostalCode = '';
        } 
    }
    for(RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c acclist:[Select Rfleet_Billing_Account__c from RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c where id in:orderids]){
        if(acclist.Rfleet_Billing_Account__c !=null)
            accids.add(acclist.Rfleet_Billing_Account__c);
    }
    system.debug('accountid---->'+accids);
    list<Account>acclist=[select id,Rfleet_City__c,Rfleet_Country__c,Rfleet_State_Province__c,Rfleet_Street_Name__c,Rfleet_Street_Number__c,Rfleet_Zip_Code__c from account where id in:accids];
    list<Account>accDocumentlist=[select id,BillingCity,BillingCountry,BillingPostalCode,BillingState,BillingStreet from account where id in:AccDocid];
    for(Account Od:acclist){
        for(Order updateadress:trigger.new){
            if(updateadress.Rfleet_Vehicle_Billed_Customer__c !=null){
                updateadress.BillingStreet = od.Rfleet_Street_Number__c+' '+od.Rfleet_Street_Name__c;
                updateadress.BillingCity= od.Rfleet_City__c;
                updateadress.BillingState = od.Rfleet_State_Province__c;
                updateadress.BillingCountry= od.Rfleet_Country__c;
                updateadress.BillingPostalCode = od.Rfleet_Zip_Code__c;
            }
        }
    }

    for(Account Ac:accDocumentlist){

        for(Order updateShipAdd:trigger.new){
            if(updateShipAdd.Rfleet_Account_for_Document__c !=null){
                updateShipAdd.ShippingStreet = Ac.BillingStreet;
                updateShipAdd.ShippingCity= Ac.BillingCity;
                updateShipAdd.ShippingState = Ac.BillingState;
                updateShipAdd.ShippingCountry= Ac.BillingCountry;
                updateShipAdd.ShippingPostalCode = Ac.BillingPostalCode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class Rfleet_populateorderfromAccount_Test {
    static testMethod void testupdatebilling(){  
        Order ord = new Order(Name='test',Status='Draft');
        ord.BillingCity = 'supreme';
        ord.BillingCountry = 'india';
        ord.BillingPostalCode = '45632';
        insert ord;
        ord.BillingCity = 'premier';
        ord.BillingCountry = 'japan';
        update ord;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following test class to get desired code coverage for your trigger

```
@isTest
public class Rfleet_populateorderfromAccount_Test {
    static testMethod void testupdatebilling(){
        Account acc = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account',
            BillingStreet = 'test Street',
            BillingCity = 'test City',
            BillingState = 'test State',
            BillingPostalCode = '12345',
            BillingCountry = 'US',
            Rfleet_Street_Number__c = '12345',
            Rfleet_Street_Name__c = 'test Street',
            Rfleet_City__c = 'test City',
            Rfleet_State_Province__c = 'test State',
            Rfleet_Country__c = 'US',
            Rfleet_Zip_Code__c = '12345'
        );
        insert acc;
        RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c accProtocol = new RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c(Rfleet_Billing_Account__c = acc.Id);
        insert accProtocol;
        Order ord = new Order(Name='test',Status='Draft');
        Test.startTest();
        insert ord;
        system.assertEquals(ord.BillingStreet,'');
        system.assertEquals(ord.ShippingStreet,'');
        ord.Rfleet_Vehicle_Billed_Customer__C = accProtocol.Id;
        update ord;
        system.assertNotEquals(ord.BillingStreet,'');
        system.assertEquals(ord.ShippingStreet,'');
        ord.Rfleet_Account_for_Document__c = acc.Id;
        system.assertNotEquals(ord.BillingStreet,'');
        system.assertNotEquals(ord.ShippingStreet,'');          
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. Your trigger uses Account and RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c objects
   along with Order object. So you should insert those records first
   before inserting your Order record.

   ```
   Account acc = new Account(
       Name = 'Test Account',
       BillingStreet = 'test Street',
       BillingCity = 'test City',
       BillingState = 'test State',
       BillingPostalCode = '12345',
       BillingCountry = 'US',
       Rfleet_Street_Number__c = '12345',
       Rfleet_Street_Name__c = 'test Street',
       Rfleet_City__c = 'test City',
       Rfleet_State_Province__c = 'test State',
       Rfleet_Country__c = 'US',
       Rfleet_Zip_Code__c = '12345'
   );
   insert acc;
   RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c accProtocol = new RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c(Rfleet_Billing_Account__c = acc.Id);
   insert accProtocol;
   ```
2. Your trigger depends on Account objects specific fields. So you
   should populate those fields in your Account record. The same
   applies for RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c object as well.

   ```
   Account acc = new Account(
       Name = 'Test Account',
       BillingStreet = 'test Street',
       BillingCity = 'test City',
       BillingState = 'test State',
       BillingPostalCode = '12345',
       BillingCountry = 'US',
       Rfleet_Street_Number__c = '12345',
       Rfleet_Street_Name__c = 'test Street',
       Rfleet_City__c = 'test City',
       Rfleet_State_Province__c = 'test State',
       Rfleet_Country__c = 'US',
       Rfleet_Zip_Code__c = '12345'
   );
   insert acc;
   ```
3. After inserting required records, now you should insert your Order
   record. Look for the surrounding Test.startTest() and
   Test.stopTest(). It marks the start of Test and stop of Test. The
   Governor limits inside this lines are reset and counted for Test
   execution.
4. Since your trigger executes depending on availability of certain
   fields, you should insert and update your Order record with and
   without values in those fields. First inserting without both fields,
   then updating with a single field and again updating with another
   field.
5. You System.Assert statements to check whether the output is as
   expected.

Hope it helps you to write better test classes in your future.

Comment: Hi,Vigneshwaran G Thank you for your response.when iam executing this code in developer console i got error like this "Field is not writeable: Account.Rfleet_Street_Number__c".please help me